# Can a projective module be singular?

Tags: ring-theory, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and $M$ be a cyclic projective $R$-module. I know that $M$ can not be singular.
My question is, if we remove the cyclic condition, will the conclusion hold?

Comment: What is your definition of singular module?

Comment: @azif00 singular usually means each element has an essential annihilator, and I hope the OP will confirm or correct after seeing this comment.

Comment: @rschwieb you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.  I remembered seeing versions of this before like this:

> If $N$ is essential in $M$, then $M/N$ is singular. The converse is true if $M$ is free.

and a variation on that

> If $M=R/T$ is a cyclic, projective, singular module, it is zero (since the result above says $T$ is essential, and if $R/T$ is projective $T$ splits out of $R$ as a summand, so $T=R$.)

Now it seems by the same logic that

> If $M=F/T$ is a projective singular module, it is zero (since $T$ is a summand of $F$ that is essential, $T=F$.)

Strangely enough when I checked, I saw the first two versions above in many sources, and did not find the third one in many places, except by [a few places](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/293065906.pdf) by T. H. Loggie who says it is well-known, and [a paper by D. Zhou](http://thaijmath.in.cmu.ac.th/index.php/thaijmath/article/viewFile/317/309) (who seems to use it without explanation.)

So all is well if you can show the direction of the first version above:

> If $M$ is free and $M/N$ is singular, then $N$ is essential in $M$.

I believe this is usually listed as an exercise but if you need help I can go into details.