# What is an example of a quotient of modules $B/A$ such that $B/A$ is singular, but $A$ is not essential in $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

In the course of thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502811/can-a-projective-module-be-singular/4504334#4504334) I asked this:

All modules here are (let us say right) $R$ modules. If $A\subseteq_{e} B$ (meaning $A$ is an [essential submodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension) of $B$, it intersects all nonzero submodules of $B$ nontrivially) then if $D/C\overset{\theta}\cong B/A$ as $R$ modules, is $C$ an essential submodule of $D$?

After running into an obvious gulf between the hypotheses and the conclusions, I realized it is probably not true and it boils down to finding **an example of $B/A$ such that $B/A$ is [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_submodule#Definitions), but $A$ is not essential in $B$.**  (Singular means the annihilator of each element is an essential right ideal of $R$.)

It's well-known$(^\ast)$ that every singular module can be expressed as a quotient $D/C$ where $C$ is essential in $D$, but I don't think one can conclude that $B/A$ singular implies $A$ is essential.

I don't have any footholds for producing quotients that are singular but not essential extensions... does anyone have an idea about this?

$(^\ast)$ indeed, you could just find a quotient of a free module isomorphic to the module, and the kernel is guaranteed to be essential by the linked question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, as you suspected.  Take
$D=(B/A)\oplus R$, and $C=0\oplus R$, for example.

Comment: Ah, it took me a second since the request was for $A$ and $B$, but yes, clearly your example is $C$ nonessential in $D$, and $D/C\cong B/A$ and we begin with $A$ essential in $B$.  Nice! That wasn't has hard as i thought it would be...

Comment: I went ahead and posed a [second version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506582/29335) should you also figure out an example in which the top of the quotient is directly irreducible. Thanks for showing me this solution!