# Good example of a singular quotient of modules that isn't a quotient of an essential extension, take 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

What is a good example of a quotient of right $R$ modules $B/A$ such that $B/A$ is [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_submodule#Definitions), but $A$ is not [essential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension) in $B$, **and** $B$ is directly irreducible?

- singular means the annihilator of each element is an essential right ideal of $R$, and
- essential means that $A$ intersects all nonzero submodules of $B$ nontrivially, and
- directly irreducible means, of course, it cannot be expressed as a direct sum of two proper submodules.

My [earlier version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4505423/29335) of this question turned out to have a simple solution using a clever trick. I'm not usually one to move goalposts, but in this case I was really hoping to be introduced to something a bit more interesting, hence the irreducibility hypothesis has been added to push harder.

Adding the criterion does not seem to be enough to create a proof that $A$ is essential in $B$, so I think there's still probably a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation of the question allows $A=0$. Restricted to this subcase, the only thing needed is that $B$ is nontrivial, singular, and not directly decomposable. For example, let $R=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Right, in my head I had already discounted examples like $\mathbb Z_2$, but probably wrongly.  I thought "$\mathbb Z_2$ is no good: it's a quotient of an essential extension."  But of course every singular module is a quotient of *some* essential extension, so that isn't unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \mathbb Z \langle x,y,z\rangle$ be the free ring of rank $3$.
Let $B$ be the $R$-module whose underlying additive group is  $V=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2, \oplus \mathbb Z_2$. Make $B$ an $R$-module by defining operators $x, y, z$ on $V$ as follows:

$x((a,b,c))=(a,0,0)$, 
$y((a,b,c)) = (0,0,c)$, 
$z((a,b,c)) = (b,0,b)$.

This module has five submodules, $0, A=R(1,0,0), C=R(0,0,1), A+C, B$.

Any element of a finite $R$-module is singular, since $R$ is free. All modules here are finite (including $B/A$), hence singular. $A$ is not an essential submodule of $B$, since $C\leq B$ is nontrivial and disjoint from $A$. $B$ is directly indecomposable since $B$ is a join irreducible element of its submodule lattice. This example differs from the other one I put on this page in that all conditions are satisfied, but $A\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and come up with this example, even though my question is a little misbegotten.

Comment: Wait... *Any element of a finite $R$-module is singular* ?  When $R$ is semisimple, for example, zero is the only singular element of any module, finite or not.  I hope we're still talking about the same definition of *singular*

Comment: @rschwieb: The sentence reads 'Any element of a finite $R$-module is singular, since $R$ is free'. An element $x$ of a finite $R$-module has annihilator $(0:x)$ which has finite index in $R$. If $(0:x)$  is not an essential right ideal of $R$, then $R$ would have a nonzero right ideal $I$ disjoint from $(0:x)$. $I$ is necessarily finite. But a free ring has no nontrivial finite one-sided ideals.

Comment: Ah, you meant free ring, not module. I see what you mean now.